# How to know if a DTD is validated or correct?

Tags: xml, dtd, dtd-parsing

I have an example of DTD script here, and I was wondering if they are valid, are there any online validator for DTD?

```
<!ELEMENT A (B* |C+,D)>
<ATTLIST A
    AA CDATA #REQUIRED
    AB CDATA #REQUIRED
    AC(0|1|2) #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT B EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST C(B)>
```

And Another Question. in the line

```
 !ELEMENT B EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST C(B)>
```

What does that actually mean? can any one provide example?

And this  `A (B* |C+,D)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [XML DTD validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) (dead link removed).

Comment: dead link now removed!

Comment: xmlvalidation.com only seems to validate XML, not the DTD.

Comment: A standard XML document needs no DTD. If you have an external DTD perhaps you could enter the DTD url?